# How to see result data values and change it using after method OR anyother best way for this?

Tags: magento2.4.4, php8

I want to change the result of \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost => Execute method. can anyone solve my query??

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code and appy your changes :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost" type="namespace\Modulename\Controller\Cart\CouponPost" />
</config>
```

Create new controller:

```
<?php
     
namespace Namespace\modulename\Controller\Cart;

class CouponPost extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost
```

Comment: Thanks for the response **@divyarajsinh barad**

I'm developing the module for marketplace release. So i don't want to override the core method. can you please help me to solve this issue for globally.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use plugin to change the execution result as given below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\CouponPost">
      <plugin name="couponpost_change_execution_result" type="namespace\Modulename\Plugin\CouponPost" />
   </type>
 </config>
```

In the plugin you can use afterExecute() method to change the result.